# Most NumPythonic way to "column stack" any number of 1-D arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy

I'd like to take any number of 1-D arrays and "column stack" them as column vectors. This works well enough using `column_stack` when I have a list of more than one such array, but when I have a single such array, `column_stack` has no effect.

I can get this to work with

```
np.array(np.matrix(j).T)
```

but this doesn't seem the clearest way to go about things.

How do I column stack a single list, such as `[1, 2, 3, 4]` with the same code I use to stack a list of such lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
In [629]: np.column_stack([[1,2,3]])
Out[629]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Are you, by any chance doing this?

```
In [631]: np.column_stack([1,2,3])
Out[631]: array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

This is doing a column stack of the scalars, effectively 0d arrays.

Look at its code:

```
arrays = []
for v in tup:
    arr = array(v, copy=False, subok=True)
    if arr.ndim < 2:
        arr = array(arr, copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=2).T
    arrays.append(arr)
return _nx.concatenate(arrays, 1)
```

It, in effect, passes each element of the input list though `array` (converting lists to arrays), and then if 1d (or 0d), it passes it again through `array`, making sure that it is 2d (followed by a transpose).

There are many ways of turning a 1d array into a 2d column vector:

```
np.atleast_2d(np.array([1,2,3])).T
np.array([1,2,3])[:,None]
np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(-1,1)
```

for a list of lists

```
In [644]: np.atleast_2d([[1,2],[3,4],[4,5]]).T
Out[644]: 
array([[1, 3, 4],
       [2, 4, 5]])
```

Look also at the code for `atleast_2d`.

Comment: The issue us with `np.column_stack([1,2,3])`.

Comment: Your input is supposed to a list of arrays or lists.  You give it a list of scalars.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's the question. What's the NumPythonic way to handle input that may be a list of scalars, or a list of such lists.

Comment: `atleast_2d` does a nice job of hiding the messy details in a function call.  Is that sufficiently 'numpythonic'?